# White web or fungus like sutff under sugar maple tree bark - peeling bark

Tags: identification, diseases, fungus, bonsai, maple

I started to notice some white web or soft fungus type stuff around crevasses of my maple tree's trunk bark. I didnt make much of it until I clipped off some of the bark, there was more of it, and then more bark came off. As seen in the second photo, all the bark down to the main trunk line came off.

What is this? what can I do about it?

The tree is like 4-5 years old. The tree was in the basement all winter, with the basement kept at ~45% humidity. The pot is a breathable polyester-type bag and was watered 1x week throughout the winter, when the soil dried out a little past the surface. The foliage came in strong for the spring and the leaves look normal. Location: Pittsburgh, PA

Thanks!
[image: Bark photo 1]
[image: Park photo 2]

Comment: Why has the tree been in a bag in your basement over the winter?

Comment: sorry, the pot is a breathable bag.

Comment: @Jurp It was in the basement all winter because it is in a 3 gallon bag style pot, it was there to winter over the winter.

Comment: It's a sugar maple, not a fig or citrus. They winter over outside just fine...

Comment: @Ecnerwal the roots are robust to frost? off topic a bit but eh

Comment: Sugar maples are very hardy; no need to have it indoors over winter unless you live in the high arctic, where there's only tundra. If your area is experiencing warmer temps right now, take it out of the basement and expose it to full sun after hardening it off for the next week.

Comment: @Jurp ahh ok. I usually dig a hole and put my potted trees in there for the winter but i got lazy. Also, a clarification, the tree has been outside since the temps have been consistently above zero. I was just providing background on where it was during the winter.